# Error: "error creating aufs mount to" when building dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I get this error when I try to build a docker file

```
 error creating aufs mount to /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt   
 /6c1b42ce1a98b1c0f2d2a7f17c196221445f1054566065d4c607e4f1b99930eb-init:   
 invalid argument
```

What does it mean? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 61):

I had some unresolved errors after removing `/var/lib/docker/aufs`, which a couple extra steps cleared up.

To add to @benwalther [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31467799/2246784), since I lack the reputation to comment:

```
# Cleaning up through docker avoids these errors
#   ERROR: Service 'master' failed to build:
#     open /var/lib/docker/aufs/layers/<container_id>: no such file or directory
#   ERROR: Service 'master' failed to build: failed to register layer:
#     open /var/lib/docker/aufs/layers/<container_id>: no such file or directory
docker rm -f $(docker ps -a -q)
docker rmi -f $(docker images -a -q)

# As per @BenWalther's answer above
sudo service docker stop
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker/aufs

# Removing the linkgraph.db fixed this error:
#   Conflict. The name "/jenkins_data_1" is already in use by container <container_id>.
#   You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.
sudo rm -f /var/lib/docker/linkgraph.db


sudo service docker start
```

Comment: This would be fine as an answer on its own (not a comment) if you make sure it's complete.  Just provide any necessary attribution.

Comment: I also encountered the "failed to register layer: open /var/lib/docker/aufs/layers/<container_id>: no such file or directory" error.
This seemed to almost do the trick for me, except that I also had to clear the image aufs folder (/var/lib/docker/image/aufs)

Comment: After stoping docker, I had to clear everything with `rm -rf /var/lib/docker/*`, before it started to work.

Comment: Hi,
I have a similar problem, and hope someone can help me. I've tried to reproduce the following post on cross/compiling for the Onion2+:
 https://rawsite.onioniot.com/2bt-cross-compiling-c-programs-part-1/

The problem is that after downloading the image, I get the following error message:
_failed to register layer: open /var/lib/docker/aufs/layers/cfad77b8e9fcb568a0d806fce422590eded5babb91d5d5de8e5c6bfa310bf78e: no such file or directory_

Could anybody point me to the possible solution? 
I'm using  Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS, and docker 17.05.0-ce

Comment: I followed these steps while also adding a `daemon.json` file at `/etc/docker/` with the single setting of `"storage-driver": "devicemapper"` before starting the docker service again. That did the trick for me on a persistent ubuntu usb.

Comment: docker rm -f $(docker ps -a -q)
docker rmi -f $(docker images -a -q)
These two commands save my day. Thanks!

Answer (score 22):

If you try to use docker inside a persistent enable Live CD, you may encounter this error. I guess, it is due to the fact that you can't mount aufs inside overlayfs mounts, which is the persistent layer.

The solution was simply using different driver. I've used `vfs` in `/etc/docker/daemon.json`

Here it is

```json
{
    "storage-driver": "vfs"
}
```

Comment: Ive used this answer when trying to run a docker service inside a docker container and it worked perfectly. I know its not best practice to do that but it works well for my needs.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Do it if you are running ubuntu from a live usb or any other removable media. Thanks mate, you saved my day!

Comment: I needed to build Docker inside Docker, this helped.

Comment: It is worth noting that vfs driver has some limitations and is not as performant because it needs to a deep copy of each underlying layer. https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/vfs-driver/. If you are using an external hard disk (or other removable media) as a dev environment, a simple alternative solution is to have another ext4 partition in the same drive and point docker to use that https://gist.github.com/nileshsimaria/ec2ea6847d494d2a1935c95d7c4b7155

Comment: I have been just saved by this answer. Thank you.

Comment: Same issue happening for us , where we are running docker containers in AKS with AzureDisk and Azure-file as Persistent volume. So will this daemon.json file content is same for the  Azure Disk and  AzureFile based persistent volumes?  I tried above value "vfs", but the volume is  not getting mounted.

Comment: @Vowneee unfortunately I can't tell now. Not actively using docker or in development

Answer (score 15):

I have removed `/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff` and got the same problem:

> error creating aufs mount to /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/blah-blah-init: invalid argument

It solved by running the following commands:

```
docker stop $(docker ps -a -q);
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q);
docker rmi -f $(docker images -a -q)
```

Comment: did not fix it ... solution in another answer ... uninstall docker assure dir /var/lib/docker is removed then reinstall docker

Comment: Worked for me after having deleted all the content from the aufs folder. Thanks!

Comment: Worked! Just had to add `sudo` for it to work on my EC2, so it became `sudo docker stop $(sudo docker ps -a -q);` for example

Answer (score 13):

AUFS is unable to mount the docker container filesystem.

This is either because: the path is already mounted - or - there's a race condition in docker's interaction with AUFS, due to the large amount of existing volumes.

To solve this, try the following:

1. restart the docker service or daemon and try again.
2. check `mount` for aufs mounted on any paths under `/var/lib/docker/aufs/`. If found, stop docker, then `umount` them (need sudo).

   example:

`mount`

`none on /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/55639da9aa959e88765899ac9dc200ccdf363b2f09ea933370cf4f96051b22b9 type aufs (rw,relatime,si=5abf628bd5735419,dio,dirperm1)`

then
    `sudo umount /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/55639da9aa959e88765899ac9dc200ccdf363b2f09ea933370cf4f96051b22b9`

3. If that doesn't work, stop docker, then `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker/aufs`. You will lose any existing stopped containers and all images. But this is just about guaranteed to solve the problem.

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately on my system I could not resolve this with the above answers. The docker administration kept remembering a certain file in the aufs layer that it couldn't reach anymore. Other solutions didn't work either. So if this is an option for you, you could try the following fix: uninstall/purge `docker` and `docker-engine`:

```
apt-get purge docker docker-engine
```

Then make sure *everything* from `/var/lib/docker` is removed.

```
rm -rf /var/lib/docker
```

After that install docker again.

Answer (score 6):

I'm using Raspbian with Raspberry 4

Best way to do it..

Check your docker version with:
`sudo docker info` and check "Storage Driver"

1. `sudo systemctl stop docker`
2. `sudo nano /etc/docker/daemon.json`
3. write this code below and save it

```
{
    "storage-driver": "vfs"
}
```

4. `sudo systemctl start docker`

altought vfs... has a performance issue and could not be the best choice... :)

Answer (score 5):

I just had a similar issue on Lubuntu (Ubuntu 4.15.0-20-generic) with Docker CE 18.03. None of the described options helped.

It appears that latest docker versions use the overlay2 storage driver. However some applications require aufs. Thus a possible fix might be to simply use this docker guide to change the storage driver to aufs (simply replace "overlay2" with "aufs") as [in this guide.](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/overlayfs-driver/#configure-docker-with-the-overlay-or-overlay2-storage-driver)

Comment: Same for me: https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/vfs-driver/ - encountered when using docker in docker

Comment: when i include vfs in daemon.json. Works for me too.

Answer (score 2):

I am running a container inside another container(also installed docker in that container) and is trying to create an aufs storage on top of an overlayfs mount, which is not possible. So, I also change the host overlyfs storage to aufs. It's solve my issue. To check storage driver use below command.
`docker info`

The solution was simply using different driver. I've used aufs in /etc/docker/daemon.json

Here it is

```
{
    "storage-driver": "aufs"
}
```

For detailed explanation read below documentation.
[Docker storage documentation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/overlayfs-driver/)

Answer (score 0):

In windows after a restart, docker machine problem is solved for me.

Use these commands:

```
docker-machine stop
docker-machine start
docker-compose up
```

Answer (score 0):

A similar issue arose while I was using Docker in Windows:

```
ERROR: Service 'daemon' failed to build: error creating overlay mount
to /var/lib/docker/overlay2/83c98f716020954420e8b89e6074b1af6
1b2b86cd51ac6a54724ed263b3663a2-init/merged: no such file or directory
```

The problem occurred after having removed a volume from the image's `Dockerfile`, rebuilding the image and then rebooting the PC. Maybe this is a common cause?

I managed to solve the problem by clicking `Docker` -> `Settings` -> `Reset` -> `Reset to factory defaults...`

All my images were subsequently lost but that didn't matter for me. I also figured that removing the VM disk image (the path to which can be found under the `Advanced` tab in `Settings`) could solve the issue. I haven't tried this approach however.

Comment: I had a similar issue with docker toolbox and considered your option but reinstalling it not even with erasing its machine and Virtualbox file didn't help, I tried to recreated a 'merge' subfolder one by one, and it seemed to advance, however, even removing the entire overlay2 folder didn't seem to help, nor fiddling with administrative mode , it somehow always recreated on the fly new randomly hash named folders missing the merged folder

Answer (score 0):

I put this answer also here, as the google search lead me here since the @whitebrow's answer contains what  term I searched for in google
`ERROR: Service '***' failed to build: error creating overlay mount
to /var/lib/docker/overlay2/***/merged: no such file or directory`

In my case, the working workaround surprisingly was to restrict the number of 'RUN' docker building commands/layers, since if the number surpassed 60 layers/commands, it always ended up with that missing 'merged' folder error, no matter what was the contents of the command, even simple command such as `RUN ls -la` ended up with that error, if the total number of such/any commands was higher than about 60, strange. `Merged` subfolder was always missing, though even when I automatically generated all the merged subfolders, always was created on the fly a new layer with a new hash, which was missing that subfolder.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue.I resolved it by adding the storage driver to /etc/docker/daemon.json

you can refer this link as well to see other driver options.
Visit https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/select-storage-driver/