# Docker: error creating aufs mount to /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/15396ee0f38d161382f104e11c94b6ca0efafe10f9952e1dfba4f548009fbe59-init: invalid argument

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, kernel, mount

I'm trying to build a Docker vm and continuously get this error:

> error creating aufs mount to /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/15396ee0f38d161382f104e11c94b6ca0efafe10f9952e1dfba4f548009fbe59-init:
>   invalid argument

I'm on Ubuntu 14 using Docker version 1.11.2, build b9f10c9.
Here is the code for the Dockerimage:

```
FROM ubuntu:trusty
MAINTAINER Fernando Mayo <fernando@tutum.co>, Feng Honglin <hfeng@tutum.co>
# Install packages
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get -y install vim supervisor git curl unzip apache2 libapache2-mod-php5 pwgen php-apc php5-mcrypt php5-mysql php5-curl&& \
  echo "ServerName localhost" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf


# Install Composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
RUN composer global require "laravel/installer"
ENV PATH ~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH

# Add image configuration and scripts
ADD start-apache2.sh /start-apache2.sh
ADD start-mysqld.sh /start-mysqld.sh
ADD run.sh /run.sh
RUN chmod 755 /*.sh
ADD my.cnf /etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf
ADD supervisord-apache2.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord-apache2.conf
ADD supervisord-mysqld.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord-mysqld.conf
ADD php.ini /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
ADD 000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf


# config to enable .htaccess
RUN a2enmod rewrite


# Copy over private key, and set permissions
ADD .ssh /root/.ssh


# Get aws stuff
RUN curl "https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/awscli-bundle.zip" -o "awscli-bundle.zip"
RUN unzip awscli-bundle.zip
RUN ./awscli-bundle/install -i /usr/local/aws -b /usr/local/bin/aws


#####This section has been moved into the run.sh to allow for cached builds that get the most up to date git repository. This is done by using ENTRYPOINT rather than RUN
# Clone the repo
RUN rm -rd /var/www/html
#RUN git clone ssh://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/Server /var/www/html
# Set file permissions
#RUN chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/storage 
#RUN chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/bootstrap/cache
ENTRYPOINT /run.sh
###########################################################################################





# Environment variables to configure php
ENV PHP_UPLOAD_MAX_FILESIZE 10M
ENV PHP_POST_MAX_SIZE 10M




EXPOSE 80 3306
CMD ["/run.sh"]
```

How can I fix this mounting problem?

Edit: Can running the host os on a live usb, specifically ubuntu, cause this problem?

Also I tried the suggestions from [Error: "error creating aufs mount to" when building dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30984569/error-error-creating-aufs-mount-to-when-building-dockerfile)
but it didn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: "error creating aufs mount to" when building dockerfile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30984569/error-error-creating-aufs-mount-to-when-building-dockerfile)

Comment: It seems similar but that fix didn't work

Comment: Hi Tyler, did you ever solve this? I have the same problem trying to run docker on live usb

Comment: @Reza we never fixed this.

Comment: @BMitch would you please post an Answer ? Because your comment is basically the answer to this question

Comment: @MADforFUNandHappy Done.

Answer (score 2):

Live usb is almost certainly not ext4, or one of the other supported filesystems. Most likely it's doing overlay, and I don't think you can mount an overlayfs on top of an overlayfs.

You can lookup your current filesystem for /var/lib/docker with a `mount` command. E.g. in my local environment (I'm symlinked, hence the extra dot in my path and files showing in homelv):

```
# df /var/lib/docker/.
Filesystem                               1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/bmitch--vg-homelv 720798904 437701948 246459468  64% /home

# mount | grep /dev/mapper/bmitch
/dev/mapper/bmitch--vg-homelv on /home type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
```

Note the "type ext4" in the mount output.

Docker has a list of [supported backing filesystems](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/#supported-backing-filesystems):

> - overlay2, overlay:  xfs with ftype=1, ext4
> - aufs:   xfs, ext4
> - devicemapper:   direct-lvm
> - btrfs:  btrfs
> - zfs:    zfs
> - vfs:    any filesystem

Answer (score 0):

`aufs` is a Docker storage driver. Docker storage drivers control how images and containers are stored on your filesystem. They’re the mechanism that lets you create images, start containers, and modify writable layers. `aufs` was the default storage driver before `overlay2`.

Now the issue may be that your Docker configuration may have different setup for the storage driver. The solution is to fix that configuration to use `aufs` like this:

1. Stop Docker

   ```
   sudo systemctl stop docker
   ```
2. Open the Docker deamon file

   ```
   sudo vi /etc/docker/daemon.json
   ```
3. Add the following to the deamon file and save it

   ```
   {
       "storage-driver": "aufs"
   }
   ```
4. Start Docker again

   ```
   sudo systemctl start docker
   ```

Reference: Official Docker [Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/overlayfs-driver/#configure-docker-with-the-overlay-or-overlay2-storage-driver) (for configuring `overlay2`)