# Failed to start docker containers after normal updating Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ubuntu-14.04

My system is `Ubuntu 14.04` with original kernel being `3.13`

```
$ uname -a
Linux dai-fp-adrecognizer 3.13.0-161-generic #211-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 3 14:52:35 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

My container used to run well on the system. The `docker-compose.yml` is as below:

```
version: '3'
services:
  scheduler:
    image: dreg.be/tvacr/dai-ws-server:1.0.2
    volumes:
      - /etc/dai-wsserver/ws_server_conf.ini:/etc/dai-wsserver/ws_server_conf.ini
    ports:
      - 6789:6789
    command: /etc/dai-wsserver/ws_server_conf.ini
```

This afternoon I did install `ffmpeg` on my system following [this instruction](https://www.faqforge.com/linux/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-ubuntu-14-04/). Basically below commands were executed:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

After that I learned that my container suddenly stopped. I tried to restart it but it always failed printing out this error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:297: copying bootstrap data to pipe caused \"write init-p: broken pipe\"": unknown.
```

After doing some searches I found [a bug report](https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/591) for the issue. I then followed [the most upvoted comment](https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/591#issuecomment-463337254) that suggests to upgrade kernel to `4.4`:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-xenial
sudo reboot
```

Now my kernel is `4.4`:

```
$ uname -a
Linux dai-fp-adrecognizer 4.4.0-146-generic #172~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 5 16:51:29 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

But my container still fails to start printing out different errors:

```
$ docker-compose up
Creating dai-wsserver_scheduler_1 ... error

ERROR: for dai-wsserver_scheduler_1  Cannot create container for service scheduler: error creating aufs mount to /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/79d5913e12e2439a40f1dfbfa2b6b615ef476f5c2c4694e0dd8726bb17e52dae-init: no space left on device

ERROR: for scheduler  Cannot create container for service scheduler: error creating aufs mount to /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/79d5913e12e2439a40f1dfbfa2b6b615ef476f5c2c4694e0dd8726bb17e52dae-init: no space left on device
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

I did check space left on my system, all should look good:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7.9G   12K  7.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  344K  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/xvda1       12G  6.7G  4.5G  61% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            7.9G  7.9G     0 100% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user

$ sudo du -h --max-depth=1 /var/lib/docker/aufs
288K    /var/lib/docker/aufs/layers
300K    /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt
2.7G    /var/lib/docker/aufs/diff
2.7G    /var/lib/docker/aufs
```

I couldn't figure out what happened with my system and how to fix it. Helps are appreciated!

Comment: Do you have to be on 14.04?  That is getting pretty.  I recall starting with docker in the spring of 2014 so 13.10 and 14..04 _probably_ work but it may require extra hoops.  I'd upgrade.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I have to say... yes. Our system is currently stick to `14.04`. We have plan to bump to `18.04` but it would take months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did find out a solution for my problem following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35630425/2589553). In short, I did clear `aufs` stuff under `/var/lib/docker`

```
sudo service docker stop
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker/aufs
sudo rm -f /var/lib/docker/linkgraph.db
sudo service docker start
```

Of course **all images will be gone**. But it's fine, I can just re-pull images.

Answer (score 0):

It worked BEFORE installing ffmpeg (and the related system changes); can you roll back to the 'known good' state when everything worked correctly? From that point I would look at what changed ffmpeg make to the system; that is where the error's root cause will be.